# no translation file found for default language

Tags: python, django

I use Python3.5 and Django 1.9.6.
When I try to perform command: migrate or makemigrations I've got error:

```
"No translation files found for default language en-us."
```

My setting.py is as follows:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE ='en-us'    
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'    
USE_I18N = True    
USE_L10N = True    
USE_TZ = True
```

I tried to add below string `"LANGUAGE_CODE"`:

```
LANGUAGES = (('en', gettext('English'))
```

as it's written in tutorial, but it doesn't help, cmd has started getting new error.

Comment: did you `makemessages`?...

Comment: No,I didn't.I'll try!Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue while setting up [BookWyrm](https://docs.joinbookwyrm.com/install-dev.html) and indeed as [Sayse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324033/sayse) suggested in the comments, running `makemessages` solved the issue for me.

Going by the [django-admin documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemessages): `django-admin makemessages` should work if the `LANGUAGE_CODE` is specified in your settings file or you can specify the locale via the `--locale` or `-l` option.